# Limiting the memory used by a task in subprocess in Linux

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I want to make sure that when in Linux I use the subprocess module in Python to call Maple to do some computations not more than 50MB of RAM memory are used.

Right now I use this code:

```
list_subprocess = ["maple"] + ["-i"] + [maple_file]
task = subprocess.Popen(
    list_subprocess, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
task.communicate(timeout=30)
```

Where 'timeout=30' makes sure that the computations don't take longer than 30 seconds.

I would like a similar command that makes sure that the computations don't use more than 50MB of RAM memory.

Comment: Take a look at this https://gist.github.com/s3rvac/f97d6cbdfdb15c0a32e7e941f7f4a3fa

Comment: I think the normal sequence for something like this is (1) Call `os.fork()` to create a child process, (2) In the child process, call `resource.setrlimit()` to establish the desired limits, and finally (3) call one of the `os.exec*()` functions (e.g. `os.execl()`, `os.execv())`, etc.)  I'm not sure if there's a higher-level way to reliably do this.  You want to make sure the limit is in place before executing the program in the subprocess, since otherwise there's no guarantee it won't already be exceeded.

Comment: @Superbman That does not work for me. I receive the error `/opt/maple2021/bin.X86_64_LINUX/cmaple: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: failed to map segment from shared object` and if I remove the argument `preexec_fn=limit_virtual_memory` from `subprocess.Popen` it works perfectly.